# Наследование UserControl. Как получить доступ к унаследованным Control в DesignTime?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Создал *UserControl1.cs* `class UserControl1 : UserControl`. Накидал элементов управления `... :Control` и компонентов `... :Component`. Создал ещё *UserControl2.cs*. Изменил предка на `class UserControl2 : UserControl1` в *UserControl2.cs* и *UserControl2.Designer.cs*. Открыл *UserControl2.cs* в конструкторе. Весь макет унаследовался, но доступа к изменению свойств нет. Вернулся к предку и проставил в его конструкторе всем "контролам" и компонентам свойство `Modifiers` значением `Protected`. "Контролы" так и не доступны для изменений свойств, а у компонентов часть свойств доступна. Как сделать, чтобы и у "контролов" часть свойств была доступна для изменения?

**Обновление**

Как оказалось, важно какие именно "контролы" у меня на предке : *DataGridView* и *ToolStrip*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вольный перевод https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089289/cannot-visually-change-datagridview-in-inherited-form

> Просто унаследуйте элемент управления и укажите правильный DesignerAttribute:

```
[Designer(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner))]
public class InheritedDataGridView : DataGridView { }
```

> Теперь используйте InheritedDataGridView везде, где бы вы хотели иметь наследуемый DataGridView.
>   Работает превосходно

Аналогично для WebBrowser, ToolStrip, ToolStripPanel, TableLayoutPanel, FlowLayoutPanel

Answer (score 2):

[Пошаговое руководство. Демонстрация визуального наследования](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1z3efhd2(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Не все элементы управления поддерживают визуальное наследование от базовой формы. Не поддерживают сценарий, описанный в этом *(Пошаговое руководство. Демонстрация визуального наследования - прим. 3per)* пошаговом руководстве, следующие элементы управления:
>
> - WebBrowser
> - ToolStrip
> - ToolStripPanel
> - TableLayoutPanel
> - FlowLayoutPanel
> - DataGridView
>
> Эти элементы управления в производной форме всегда доступны только для чтения, независимо от используемых модификаторов (private, protected или public).
>
> ...
>
> Наследование для пользовательских элементов управления работает таким же образом.

Увы. Очень жаль, это именно то, что я собирался наследовать